# NgDraggable : drag into nested drop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to use ngDraggable for angularjs to build an interface builder.

My problem is, I can't drop item into a a nested droppable div.

Example will be better.
My draggable list :

```
<div class="col-md-3 components-list">
    <div class="category ng-scope" ng-repeat="category in componentCategories">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">Containers</h4>

        <div class="drag-object ng-scope" ng-repeat="component in category.components">

            <h5 class="ng-binding">12</h5>
            <div class="component-content" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="component" draggable="false" style=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drag-object ng-scope" ng-repeat="component in category.components">

            <h5 class="ng-binding">6</h5>
            <div class="component-content" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="component" draggable="false"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My nested droppable container :

```
<div class="col-md-9 builder-container" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete(container, $data, $event)"> <!-- Parent container -->

    <div ng-repeat="component in container track by $index" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="component" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess(container, $data,$event)" >
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:blue;min-height:100px;border:1px solid black">
            <div class="builder-container" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete(component.container, $data, $event)"> <!-- Child container -->
                <div ng-repeat="component in component.container track by $index" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="component" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess(component.container, $data,$event)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to drop an item, either in the main container, or in the nested container.

Any idea would help a lot...
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

They way I solved the problem recently was to create a service (dragRegistrar) that you register the item's state to and then assign the state on dragenter, then use that service to communicate where you want that information to go.

```
<div drag-directive="information">
    <p> stuff</p>
</div>
<div drop-directive="outer">
  <h1>Drop Stuff here.</h1>
  <div drop-directive="inner">
    <h2> or in here </h2>
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('app').directive('dragDirective', ['dragRegistrar', function(dragRegistrar){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      var el = elem[0];
      el.draggable = true;
      elem.on('dragend', function(){
        moveInformationToThing(attr.dragDirective, dragRegistrar.thing);
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
}]).directive('dropDirective', ['dragRegistrar', function(dragRegistrar){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
       elem.on('dragenter', function(){
         dragRegistrar.thing = attr.dropDirective;
         scope.$apply();
       });
    }
  };
}]).service('dragRegistrar', function(){
  return {thing: null};
});
```

**Edit:**
One of the problems I had when dealing with this had to do with an element within the directive would cause the dragleave event to fire-- even though the event was taking place on a descendant element of the directive. To get around this, I did:

```
elem.on('dragleave', function(event){
  if(attr.myDropover === 'inner'){
    if(event.target !== elem[0]){ return; }
  }
});
```